# Unable to convert class syntax to function syntax for a Linked List

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Okay so I'm learning Data Structures where my tutorial is following `class` syntax. So now I am trying to convert it to `function` declarations as I want to practice Linked Lists with that notation. Can anybody help me with the conversion? I need only one method to be converted and I'll be able to do the rest of them.

Here's the code I have with `class` syntax:

```
class Node {
    constructor( val ) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class SinglyLinkedList {
    constructor () {
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }

    push( val ) {
        const newNode = new Node( val );

        if ( !this.head ) {
            this.head = newNode;
            this.tail = this.head;
        } else {
            this.tail.next = newNode;
            this.tail = newNode;
        }
        this.length++
        return this;
    }

}

const list = new SinglyLinkedList();

list.push( 'HELLO' );
list.push( 'WORLD' );
```

Here's what I tried so far to achieve function-based approach:

```
function Node( val ) {
  this.val = val;
  this.next = null;
}

let head = null;
let tail = null;
let length = 0;

const SinglyLinkedListFunc = function() {
    const newNode = new Node( 'HELLO' );
};

SinglyLinkedListFunc()
```

This is what I could achieve so far. And I'm stuck with it and I don't know what to do next. Someone please help

Comment: Uh, a linked list (node) is an object. You cannot change that to become local variables.

Comment: Just because you use a constructor function doesnt make it functional. Whatever. You need two constructor functions. One for the Node and one for the List.

Comment: A truly functional (and thus: immutable) approach would make `push` inefficient as it would need to copy the whole list. Why would you want that?

Comment: @s.khan "functional" doesn't mean that you no longer use objects or classes. On the contrary, you still should, to make your code more structured! However, a functional approach means that you should no longer modify (mutate) your objects, but instead create new objects that are returned as the result of the operations (methods, functions).

Comment: @trincot: See the answer from Mulan for a reasonably efficient immutable approach

Comment: @ScottSauyet, of course, *prepending* can be done efficiently with a functional approach, but not *appending*, which is what the Asker does with their `push`. Anyway, the Asker was in the end not asking for a functional approach, but a version without the use of `class` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**functional heritage**

The linked list is a functional structure and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutation and variable reassignments. Below we implement a functional-style immutable linked list in an object-oriented interface -

```js
class Node {
  constructor(head, tail) {
    this.head = head
    this.tail = tail
  }
}

const empty = Symbol("empty")
  
class List {
  constructor(t = empty) {
    this.t = t
  }
  push(v) {
    return new List(new Node(v, this.t))
  }
  toString() {
    if (this.t == empty)
      return "∅"
    else
      return `${this.t.head} -> ${new List(this.t.tail)}`
  }
}

const l = (new List).push("a").push("b").push("c")
console.log(String(l))
console.log(String(l.push("d").push("e").push("f")))
console.log(String(l))
```

Notice how each call to `.push` returns a new, unmodified list -

```
c -> b -> a -> ∅
f -> e -> d -> c -> b -> a -> ∅
c -> b -> a -> ∅
```

**modules preferred, classes optional**

But I think you can do a lot better than that. By mixing functional designs and concerns directly with class-oriented semantics, we end up with strange and often inefficient programs. In functional style we write modules with ordinary functions. If an object-oriented interface is desired, only a thin wrapper around our plain functions is needed -

```js
// list.js
const empty = Symbol("empty")

const pair = (left, right) =>
  ({ left, right })

const push = (t, v) =>
  pair(v, t)

const list = (...args) =>
  args.reduce(push, empty)

const toString = t =>
  t == empty
    ? "∅"
    : `${t.left} -> ${toString(t.right)}`
  
class List {
  constructor(t = empty) { this.t = t }
  static empty() { return new List() }
  static of(...args) { return new List(list(...args)) }
  push(v) { return new List(push(this.t, v)) }
  toString() { return toString(this.t) }
}

export { default:List, empty, pair, push, list, toString }
```

In your **main** module we will import `list` from our **list** module -

```js
// main.js
import List from "./list.js"

const l = List.empty().push("a").push("c").push("d")
console.log(String(l))
console.log(String(l.push("d").push("e").push("f")))
console.log(String(l))
```

```
c -> b -> a -> ∅
f -> e -> d -> c -> b -> a -> ∅
c -> b -> a -> ∅
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your browser -

```js
// list.js
const empty = Symbol("empty")

const pair = (left, right) =>
  ({ left, right })

const push = (t, v) =>
  pair(v, t)

const list = (...args) =>
  args.reduce(push, empty)

const toString = t =>
  t == empty
    ? "∅"
    : `${t.left} -> ${toString(t.right)}`
  
class List {
  constructor(t = empty) { this.t = t }
  static empty() { return new List() }
  static of(...args) { return new List(list(...args)) }
  push(v) { return new List(push(this.t, v)) }
  toString() { return toString(this.t) }
}

// main.js
const l = List.empty().push("a").push("c").push("d")
console.log(String(l))
console.log(String(l.push("d").push("e").push("f")))
console.log(String(l))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the functional approach:

```
function Node( val, next ) {
  this.val = val;
  this.next = null;
}
 
const SinglyLinkedListFunc = function() {
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.length = 0;
};

SinglyLinkedListFunc.prototype.push = function( val ) {

  const newNode = new Node( val );

  if( !this.head ){
    this.head = newNode;
    this.tail = newNode;
  } else{
    this.tail.next = newNode;
    this.tail = newNode;
  }

    this.length++;
    return this;
}


let list = new SinglyLinkedListFunc();
list.push('HELLO');
list.push('WORLD');
```

Comment: This is not [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). `push` mutates the list which goes against *functional programming*.

Comment: I never said in my post that I want functional programming. I just wanted to use functions  instead of classes.

Comment: You also said *"with **functional** approach."*. That is something more than just writing functions.

Comment: I also said this: So now I am trying to convert it to functions

Comment: Which is indeed a step you need to perform in order to get a functional approach. But it needs more. Anyway, it seems you didn't realise what functional means to the community. It is clear now.

Comment: Yes I wouldn't know that as I am still learning remember?

Comment: No problem, I edited your question so the misunderstanding is resolved.

Comment: @s.khan: Even if a functional approach isn't what you were looking for, it is worthwhile examining the answer from Mulan which demonstrates a very different way of looking at code.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look at it.